# How to create Google App Engine Project in Eclipse Juno 4.2?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I'm trying to follow these directions to set up a new Google App Engine project:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started#creating

> To create your first Web Application, select File > New > Web Application Project from the Eclipse menu.

However, that option doesn't exist! I just installed and restarted my Eclipse.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

Had to delete .eclipse/* and after multiple restarts and running as Administrator, it worked.

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#multiuser

> After installing/updating the plugin on a multi-user install of Eclipse, I cannot see any of the plugin's toolbar icons. What's going on?
>
> Multi-user installs of Eclipse are those where the adminstrator of the machine has performed the installation of Eclipse, and non-administrators (users) run Eclipse.
>
> Unfortunately, Eclipse suffers from problems whenever a user upgrades a plugin that exists as part of the base installation; the upgraded plugin is not recognized, which means that any plugins that depend on the upgraded component will not work. When installing the Google Plugin for Eclipse as a user, it may cause Eclipse to try and install updates for already-installed plugins at the same time, which leads to the Google Plugin for Eclipse not working after the install process.
>
> There are two ways to avoid this problem:
>
> Each user should have their own install of Eclipse
>   The administrator should be the only one who installs or upgrades plugins
>   If you have already installed/upgraded the Google Plugin for Eclipse and are stuck in a broken state, the easiest way to get back to a working state is to remove your /.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_ directory, and perform the install/upgrade of the Google Plugin for Eclipse as an administrator. Note that by deleting this directory, you will be removing any plugins that the user had previously installed.

Sheesh, I wish Eclipse had more stability than features. Sometimes I prefer Notepad++ and a command prompt.

Any other questions, just contact the plugin developer directly at ahumesky@google.com.